# how to get value from other view controller and compare ..?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I have two view controllers

- SearchViewController.m
- ContentViewController.m

In SearchViewController.m  File

```
(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar*)searchBar

 {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

     NSString * searchStr = [searchBar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

     [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
     [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];  
      **searchBar.text = searchStr**;  

     #ifndef SQL_KEYWORD_PARSE
    // Process the search string for keywords
     NSMutableSet* tokens = [[Tokenizer sharedTokenizer] tokenize:searchStr];

    // Create and perform a request for existing keyword records for these tokens
    NSError* err;
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Keyword"   inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keyword IN %@",tokens];
    NSArray* aKeywords = [self.managedObjectContext  executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
   [request release];


   if (![aKeywords count])
{
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                 message:@"No records match this search; it contains no indexed keywords"
                                delegate:self
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                       otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
    return;
}
if (searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex && ([tokens count] != [aKeywords count]))
{
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                 message:@"No records match this search; it contains one or more keywords with no matches"
                                delegate:self
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                       otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
    return;
}

    // Create a filtered result set
   ((RuleSearchDataSource*) self.dataSource).exactPhrase = (searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex == 0);
   ((RuleSearchDataSource*) self.dataSource).useAll = (searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex == 1);
   ((RuleSearchDataSource*) self.dataSource).phrase = searchStr;
   ((RuleSearchDataSource*) self.dataSource).keywords = [NSSet setWithArray:aKeywords];
   #else
// Create a filtered result set
   ((RuleSearchDataSource*) self.dataSource).exactPhrase = (searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex == 0);
   ((RuleSearchDataSource*) self.dataSource).useAll =  (searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex == 1);
   ((RuleSearchDataSource*) self.dataSource).phrase = searchStr;
    #endif
    NSLog(@"String Search word :%@",searchStr);
}
```

---

ContentViewController.m File

```
(void) reloadHighlights: (ContentViewDataSource *) dataSource
{
   // Clear any existing highlights.
    for (NSArray * section in dataSource.items)
    {
   if (section.count > 0)
    {
        TTTableStyledTextItem * item = section[0];
        ContentStyledText * text = (ContentStyledText *) item.text;
        [text removeHighlights];
    //          text.font = nil;
    }
}
AppDelegate_Shared * appDelegate = (AppDelegate_Shared *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
HighlightsController * highlightController = appDelegate.highlightsController;

NSMutableArray * highlights = highlightController.highlights;
DefaultStyleSheet * styleSheet = [DefaultStyleSheet globalStyleSheet];

if (highlights)
{
        if (self.tempHighlightPassageArray != nil)
    {
 for (NSNumber * passageId in self.tempMHighlightPassageArray)
        {
            int rowIndex = [(ContentViewDataSource *) self.dataSource rowNumberForPassage:[passageId integerValue]];

            TTTableStyledTextItem * item = (TTTableStyledTextItem *) [dataSource getSectionItem:rowIndex itemIndex: 0];

 if (item.text)
 {
    ContentStyledText * text = (ContentStyledText *) item.text;
    UIColor * highlightColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]; // 

     NSString* wordsList = @"";
     NSArray * paraArray = [text.rootNode.outerText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

 // for loop for passag word count
 for (NSUInteger iCount=0; iCount < [paraArray count ]; iCount++) 
 {
    if([paraArray[iCount] **compare:@"the"** options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]== NSOrderedSame)
    {
    if([wordsList isEqualToString:@""])
     {
       wordsList = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu" , (unsigned long)iCount];
     }
     else{
         wordsList = [wordsList stringByAppendingString:@"|"];
         wordsList = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu" , (unsigned long)iCount];
       }
  }
  if(![wordsList isEqualToString:@""]){
   NSArray* wordArray = [wordsList componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];

   for (NSUInteger iCount=0; iCount < [wordArray count ]; iCount++)          {
    [text addHighlightFrom:[wordArray[iCount] integerValue] to:[ wordArray[iCount] integerValue] color:highlightColor stroke:highlightColor];
    //text.rootNode.outerHTML = text.rootNode.outerHTML;
    // return ;
             }
       }
 }
 }
        }
    }

    for (Highlight * highlight in highlights)
    {       
        if (highlight.sectionId == [self.section.id integerValue])
        {
            [self loadHighlight:highlight dataSource: dataSource styleSheet: styleSheet];
        }
    }
}

  if (mSelectionHighlight && mSelectionHighlight.highlightColor == kEraseColor)
  {
     // Erase color highlights don't get added to the list, but we still want to show a selection.
    [self loadHighlight:mSelectionHighlight dataSource: dataSource styleSheet: styleSheet];
  }

}
```

I want to pass value from SearchViewController ==> of searchBar.text = searchStr value to the ContentViewController ==> to pass value in **compare:@"the"**

I am new in iOS development.

Comment: Create a property with NSString in ContentViewController.h. And set the property when you are calling ContentViewController object in SearchViewController. Access the same in ContentViewController.

Comment: is the `ContentViewController` called from the `SearchViewController` or is it the other way round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a public @`property` in `ContentViewController` to hold the `NSString` from the texbox. Then set it before pushing the view controller. Situations you might have:

A) You are using a `storyboard` to define the `contentcontroller` and `searchcontroller`. In this case you can Ctrl drag the `ContentController` with the mouse from the `storyboard` to the `SearchController.h` file and create an `IBoutlet` for it (so you now have access to the `ContentController` from the Search one, you can set the string value when user enters text)

B) You are pushing `ContentController` manually, then set the property before pushing it.

C) You are pushing it via `storyboard`. Then use the method - `(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`. This method is called before getting pushed so you have a chance to set the properties of the pushed controller there.

Comment: Here's how to pass the data via a segue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266024/how-to-get-value-from-other-view-controller-and-compare